# Definite integral as the limit of a sum

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I tried, but I could only reach this far, is converting the whole equation in an equivalent integral equation.

[image]

Comment: What is the function you have been asked to integrate?

Comment: What is that $\;m\;$ there? Anyway, you can't leave $\;n\;$ in your last expression, with the integral, **after** you passed to the limit $\;n\to\infty\;$ ...

Comment: The one in the box.

Comment: @PrakharSankrityayan I've no idea what that means.

Comment: Don't know. The question says nothing about m. Let's assume it to be a constant!

Comment: Please learn MathJax

Comment: @PrakharSankrityayan I cannot succeed in  making this limit a Riemann integral. Perhaps instead of that $\;m\;$ it is $\;rm\;$ ?

Comment: What if it's RM ?

Comment: @PrakharSankrityayan Sorry, I meant $\;r^3m\;$, and then sum is the integral $$\int_0^1\frac{(x^2-x^3m)^{1/3}}xdx$$ which, by the way, isn't the nicest thing out there, either...

Comment: @Prakhar If you could provide me the answer and present the problem clearly I could help you. If you are not fimiliar with MathJax, send the original picture of the problem with answer, i will help you